# .NET HttpClient - Ignoring Certificate Errors Conditionally

Tags: .net, http, ssl, certificate

In my ASP.NET Web Application, I **sometimes** need to make request to HTTPS endpoints by specifying target IP in address, not giving domain. Naturally this causes certificate errors. I want to ignore those certificate issues and continue to make calls over System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.

I need this behavior conditionally, depending on the request. That's why;

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

is not an option for me. Because it changes the bevahior globally.

How can I specify to ignore certificate errors on per request basis?

Comment: "Because it changes the behavior globally", but you can properly handle all cases if you set a proper callback (instead of blindly returning true all the time).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on a per request basis like so:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
(httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
{
return true;
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```